# knockout foreach doesnt update observables

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

For some reason I am not able to create correctly observableyarray so that foreach item observables are updated. Also I am not able to get updated model (observablearay) on click binding, that is related with above.

```
 <div>        
    <!-- THIS NEVER UPDATES IF YOU CHANGE TEXTAREA-->
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>

    <div data-bind="foreach: Items">
        <div data-bind="text: TestProperty"></div>
        <textarea data-bind="text: DataInput"></textarea>        
        <!-- THIS NEVER UPDATES IF YOU CHANGE TEXTAREA-->
        <span data-bind="text: DataInput"></span>  
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click: test">Save</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var RiskItemModel = function (item) {
    var self = this;

    self.DataInput = ko.observable(item.DataInput);
    self.TestProperty = ko.observable("test");
};

var PortfolioRiskModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.Items = ko.observableArray();
    // fill with initial data

    if (data) {        
        $.each(data.Items, function (index, item) {
           self.Items.push(ko.observable(new RiskItemModel(item)));
            //self.Items.push(new RiskItemModel(item));
        });
    };

    self.test = function () {
        // I AM ALWATYS GETTING OLD VALUES HERE!
        alert(ko.unwrap(ko.unwrap(self.Items)[0]).DataInput());
    };
};


var data = {
    "$id": "1",
        "Items": [{
        "DataInput": "first"
    }
                  /*, {
        "DataInput": "second"
    }*/

    ]
};

var ChartSelectedRiskType = new PortfolioRiskModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(ChartSelectedRiskType);
```

You can play with jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/L3tJL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bound your data to the wrong attributte in the textarea.

Should be like this:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: DataInput"></textarea>
```